# Rotate UIViewController programmatically

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I'm trying to force the screen to rotate from portrait to landscape following a segue.

I've had a look for an answer but all of the ones I've come across suggest using `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` which doesn't work, and I get a warning message that it is depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:")
                                   withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
}
```

View will be rotated to Lanscape Left orientation.
You can rotate view to Landscape Right orientation use this version of code:

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:")
                                   withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
}
```

But - Apple may reject your app because this is very near to Private APIs. I was use this code without problems (except warnings in Xcode), but all is possible.